# Get Access Token from Twilio in Golang

Tags: go, twilio

I use Golang for my backend and I need to get an Access Token from Twilio but I can't find any available library for Golang.
The example code in NodeJS is:

```
const AccessToken = require('twilio').jwt.AccessToken;
const VideoGrant = AccessToken.VideoGrant;

// Used when generating any kind of Access Token
const twilioAccountSid = 'ACxxxxxxxxxx';
const twilioApiKey = 'SKxxxxxxxxxx';
const twilioApiSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';

// Create an access token which we will sign and return to the client,
// containing the grant we just created
const token = new AccessToken(twilioAccountSid, twilioApiKey, twilioApiSecret);
token.identity = 'alice';

// Create a Video grant which enables a client to use Video 
// and limits access to the specified Room (DailyStandup)
const videoGrant = new VideoGrant({
    room: 'DailyStandup'
});

// Add the grant to the token
token.addGrant(videoGrant);

// Serialize the token to a JWT string
console.log(token.toJwt());
```

I tried this library -> https://github.com/xaviiic/twilioGo but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the library you linked (https://github.com/xaviiic/twilioGo) the code/methods etc. tracks very closely to the `NodeJS` sample-code:

```
import twilio "github.com/xaviiic/twilioGo"

var (
    accountID = "AC...."
    keyID     = "SK...."
    secret    = "....."
)

token := twilio.NewAccessToken(accountID, keyID, secret)
identity := "alice"
token.SetIdentity(identity)

videoGrant := twilio.NewVideoGrant("DailyStandup")
token.AddGrant(videoGrant)

log.Println(token.ToJWT())
```

https://play.golang.org/p/6mEpQqisITf

Note: while the above will build in a `GOPATH` env (i.e. using latest project commits) it needs some help if doing a `go modules` build:

```
# this will initially fail:
go build

# choose latest commit of this dependency - latest v0.9.1 tag appears to be incompatible
go get github.com/SermoDigital/jose@master    

go build
```